# How to make Overflow Link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you make a link that when pressed, displays more information about something without reloading the page? (i believe it is called overflow?)

an example would be here:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jiwire.android.finder&feature=featured-apps

click the MORE button under the Description section, and more description is showed and the entire webpage's content slides down WITHOUT need to reload

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
    div { background:#de9a44; margin:3px; width:80px; 
    height:40px; display:none; float:left; }
    </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      Click me!
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <script>
    $(document.body).click(function () {
    if ($("div:first").is(":hidden")) {
    $("div").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
    $("div").hide();
    }
    });

    </script>

<script>
  $(document.body).click(function () {
    if ($("div:first").is(":hidden")) {
      $("div").show("slow");
    } else {
      $("div").slideUp();
    }
  });

  </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If it needs to slide up as well, `$('div').slideToggle('slow')` would be enough.

Comment: what parts of the jquery-latest.js file would i need in order for slidedown etc to work? what lines specifically?

Comment: 'jQuery-Latest.js` file is plugin that consists of various jQuery libraries. In which `SlideUp, SlideDown and SlideToggle` does your work. However you should not remove other code in jQuery as its the supporting library code to make use of jQuery.